# Using songs.sty, how do I make a small index not consume the entire page?

Tags: songs

I'm building a song book with the songs package from songs.sourceforge.net and I'm trying to create topical indexes for songs. The small indexes consume an entire page each. I'd like to squeeze them so they don't take up a whole page.

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.7in, bottom=0.7in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\title{My MWE}

\usepackage[lyric]{songs}
\newindex{titleidx}{titleidx}
\newauthorindex{authoridx}{authoridx}
\newindex{mytopic}{mytopicidx}
\begin{document}

\songcolumns{1}

\showindex{Title Index}{titleidx}
\showindex{Author Index}{authoridx}
\showindex{My Topic}{mytopic}


\songsection{}

\begin{songs}{titleidx,authoridx}


\beginsong{Just some song}[
  by={me},
  cr={},
  li={}]

\indextitleentry[mytopic]{\songtitle}

\endsong

\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A redefinition of the internal macro `\SB@displayindex` is necessary:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.7in, bottom=0.7in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\title{My MWE}

\usepackage[lyric]{songs}
\newindex{titleidx}{titleidx}
\newauthorindex{authoridx}{authoridx}
\newindex{mytopic}{mytopicidx}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand\SB@displayindex[3]{%
  \ifsongindexes\begingroup%
    \SB@colwidth\hsize%
    \advance\SB@colwidth-#1\columnsep%
    \advance\SB@colwidth\columnsep%
    \divide\SB@colwidth#1%
    \setbox\SB@idxtitlebox\vbox{%
      \let\SB@temp\songsection%
      \ifx\chapter\undefined\else%
        \ifx\chapter\relax\else%
          \let\SB@temp\songchapter%
        \fi%
      \fi%
      \SB@temp{#2}%
    }%
    \IfFileExists{\csname SB@idxfilename@#3\endcsname.sbx}{%
      \ifx\hyperlink\undefined\let\hyperlink\@secondoftwo\fi%
      \ifx\hyperlink\relax\let\hyperlink\@secondoftwo\fi%
      \global\setbox\SB@box\vbox{%
        \null%
        \vfil%
        \unvcopy\SB@idxtitlebox%
        \vskip.5in\@minus.3in\relax%
        \hbox to\hsize{%
          \hfil%
          \vbox{%
            \hsize\SB@colwidth%
            \renewenvironment{idxblock}[1]%
              {\begin{SB@smidx}{####1}}{\end{SB@smidx}}%
            \let\\\SB@idxitemsep%
            \input{\csname SB@idxfilename@#3\endcsname.sbx}%
          }%
          \hfil%
        }%
        \vskip\z@\@plus2fil\relax%
      }%
      {\vbadness\@M\vfuzz\maxdimen%
       \splitmaxdepth\maxdepth\splittopskip\z@skip%
       \global\setbox\SB@boxii\vsplit\SB@box to\textheight}%
      \ifvoid\SB@box%
        \box\SB@boxii%
      \else%
        \global\setbox\SB@box\vbox{%
          \renewenvironment{idxblock}[1]%
            {\begin{SB@lgidx}{####1}}{\end{SB@lgidx}}%
          \let\\\SB@idxitemsep%
          \SB@idxsetup{#1}%
          \input{\csname SB@idxfilename@#3\endcsname.sbx}%
          \unskip%
        }%
        \SB@toks{\SB@makeidxcolumn{#1}}%
        \SB@cnt#1\relax%
        \loop\ifnum\SB@cnt>\@ne%
          \SB@toks\expandafter{\the\SB@toks%
            \kern\columnsep\SB@makeidxcolumn{#1}}%
          \advance\SB@cnt\m@ne%
        \repeat%
        \edef\SB@oneidxpage{\the\SB@toks}%
        \unvbox\SB@idxtitlebox%
        \vskip.2in\relax%
        \nointerlineskip%
        \null%
        \nointerlineskip%
        \SB@cnt\vbadness\vbadness\@M%
        \SB@dimenii\vfuzz\vfuzz\maxdimen%
        \loop%
          \SB@dimen\textheight%
          \ifinner\else\kern\z@\advance\SB@dimen-\pagetotal\fi%
          \global\setbox\SB@boxii\copy\SB@box%
          \global\setbox\SB@boxiii\hbox{\SB@oneidxpage}%
          \ifdim\ht\SB@box>\z@%
            \box\SB@boxiii%
            \vfil\break%
        \repeat%
        \SB@dimenii\ht\SB@boxii%
        \divide\SB@dimenii#1\relax%
        \SB@maxmin\SB@dimen>\SB@dimenii%
        \loop%
          \global\setbox\SB@box\copy\SB@boxii%
          \global\setbox\SB@boxiii\hbox{\SB@oneidxpage}%
          \ifdim\ht\SB@box>\z@%
            \advance\SB@dimen\p@%
        \repeat%
        \box\SB@boxiii%
        \global\setbox\SB@boxii\box\voidb@x%
        \vbadness\SB@cnt\vfuzz\SB@dimenii%
      \fi%
    }%
    {%
      \vbox{%Changed
        \vfil%
        \unvbox\SB@idxtitlebox%
        \vskip1em\relax%
        \hbox to\hsize{\hfil[Index not yet generated.]\hfil}%
        \vskip2em\@plus2fil\relax%Changed
      }%
    }%
    %\clearpage%Changed
  \endgroup\fi%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\songcolumns{1}

\showindex{Title Index}{titleidx}
\showindex{Author Index}{authoridx}
\showindex{My Topic}{mytopic}
\clearpage

\songsection{}

\begin{songs}{titleidx,authoridx}


\beginsong{Just some song}[
  by={me},
  cr={},
  li={}]

\indextitleentry[mytopic]{\songtitle}

\endsong

\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Version 2.13 and later of the songs package contains a special macro for this purpose.  Just put `\sepindexesfalse` in your document prelude.